# How to get declared dependencies in intellij-scala? How to get dependency trees in intellij-scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-plugin

## Question1

I am not familiar with **intellij-scala**, I have developed a **intellij plugin** to analyze sbt dependencies,
and I want to get all declared dependencies.

I found a method that seemed to be obtainable, but in the end, I realized that there were many scenarios that were not obtainable.

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/ce4785e85496fe9d9d0c315b247ca75f0062188b/scala/integration/packagesearch/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/packagesearch/SbtDependencyModifier.scala#L158

When I can obtain the declared dependencies, the **intellij plugin** can implement this jump function
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9mAB.png)

Otherwise, I will get this:
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIM4P.png)

## Question2

Can I directly obtain all dependency trees/graphs of the project in **intellij plugin**?

It seems that in Maven, I can directly obtain all dependencies?
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/fdcb966cf3a27dd9035b66076c5a5f36fded502c/plugins/maven/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/idea/maven/project/MavenProject.java#L848

In the end, I can only implement **intellij plugin** through **sbt-dependency-graph**, which obtains dependency graphs.
[show my plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP177.png)

Unfortunately, plugins based on **sbt-dependency-graph** implementation must rely on dot/graphml files.(console output seems even worse). Relying on `sbt-dependency-tree` means relying on sbt shell. But my plugin is **intellij plugin**. I can indeed call sbt shell in intellij plugin, but starting sbt shell is a bit slow, and the user must add `addDependencyTreePlugin` to enable `dependencyGraphML` and `dependencyGraphDot`, which is not good, but I do so now.

I have not found a method that can correctly obtain the declared dependency, nor have I found an **intellij method** that can correctly obtain the dependency tree.

My plugin is here, it is already usable, but it faces the above two issues.

**https://github.com/bitlap/intellij-sbt-dependency-analyzer/tree/master**

Comment: What's wrong with graphml in `dependencyGraphML`? You get XML file that any XML reader can deal with (including scala-xml) rather than some arbitrary format that you'd have to write a parser for. And a list of explicitly defined dependencies can be obtained by `show dependencyList` + `show libraryDependencies`. Without more detail this post gives an impression that all you need is in sbt BUT you don't want to use what it provides because of reasons, and so you ask how to obtain things from sbt without using means to obtains things from sbt. If there are problems, please, highlight them.

Comment: I want to obtain it in the intellij plugin, but I don't want to rely on graphml(dependencyGraphML) and dot(dependencyDot)

Comment: SBT provides these features, but the prerequisite is that I need to add `addDependencyTreePlugin` and also open the sbtshell. 
(Note: for intellij plugin, opening an sbt shell at this point may not seem a reasonable approach)

Comment: Intelli, when importing sbt build, uses sbt shell anyway. And it additionally injects its own sbt plugin, calls it to generate some XML, and then read this XML. If Jetbrains found it to be the easiest approach with their resources, I doubt anyone will suggest you a solution not involving sbt (even BSP would require you to call sbt to make .bps files).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in your project to print dependency tree.

> mvn dependency:tree

Comment: But I don't use Maven.